# Looping Issue in Number Game

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to get back to the basics, using a while loop and a bool to keep the guessing game going is cleaner and helps me learn how to usue booleans better. But this game just sticks into an infinite loop?
Is there anyway to fix this, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious

```
    namespace Guess_Number_V2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randNum = rand.Next(1, 11);
            int guessCount = 0;
            int userScore = 10;
            int userGuess;
            int perGuess = 1;
            bool correctGuess = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

            userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (correctGuess == false)
            {
                if (userGuess == randNum)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    userScore -= perGuess;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess was right, the number was {0}! Total score is {1} and you had {2} attempts.", randNum, userScore, guessCount);

                    correctGuess = true;


                }

                if (userGuess > randNum)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to high!");
                    userScore -= perGuess;
                    correctGuess = false;

                }

                else if (userGuess < randNum)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to low!");
                    userScore -= perGuess;
                    correctGuess = false;


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never prompt for another guess. If they don't guess correctly on the first try then `userGuess` will be wrong and never change.

Comment: Nice one, fixed it. Now I want to modify the the guesscount if it only took one guess for it to say well done for only taking one guess. Tho that may be a bit OTT.
Funny thing is it says stuff like took you 2 guesses but technically if you guess correctly on the 3rd guess it become the 4th guess? Kinda hard to explain if I get it right the first time it says I took 0 guesses but I didn't it took one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the prompt inside the loop or you'll never get a new `userGuess`. That's why you are getting an infinite loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

while (correctGuess == false)
{
    userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    // ...
```